# g_object_unref() member pointer of C++ Glib::Object sub-class in destructor?

Tags: c++, glib, gobject

If I have C++ class derived from `Glib::Object` with a pointer to a g_object (C-interface) from GMime:

```
 /* schematic set up of class */
 class B : public Glib::Object {
  public:
    GMimeObject * mime_object;
 };
```

the `mime_object` is created and then passed to `class B` upon instantiation. It is not `g_object_unref()`'ed. Should I `g_object_unref()` it in the destructor `class B::~B()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to unref it in the destructor. You may also need to call `g_object_ref_sink()` in the constructor to get refcounting exactly right.

`GObject`s which inherit from `GInitiallyUnowned` (rather than directly from the base `GObject`) start off with a "floating" reference which must be "sunk". This is the case for all GTK widgets for example. I don't know offhand whether this applies to `GMimeObject` or not, but the documentation will tell you (or you can call `g_object_is_floating()` at runtime to find out if you need to sink it).

Comment: I guess I should have discovered this one earlier: https://developer.gnome.org/gmime/stable/gmime-question-index.html, thanks anyway.

Comment: The answer is in fact not correct for my particular case, but I think it answers the question correctly in the general case. I should probably do a g_object_ref() in the constructor (and then unref() in the desctructor) for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably should.  It would be cleanest to also create the `mime_object` in the constructor rather than taking a raw pointer in from outside.  If you take a raw pointer from outside it may be a bit unclear who owns the object and is responsible for releasing it.

Also note that you will need to override or disable the copy constructor, else you will have a double-unref situation if `B` is copied.